# Adding an OOTB Web Part to an App for SharePoint

Tags: search, sharepoint, sharepoint-apps, webpartpage

I'm attempting to just add an OOTB Web Part (actually to create a variation of a Search Page)  in an App for SharePoint using an Office 365 Development Site for development but this happens with ANY OOTB Web Part. The default code when I create a page of course is this:

```
<%@ Page language="C#" MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master"
    Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage, 
    Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
    PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" 
    Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
    PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" 
    Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
    PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls"
    Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
    PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
  <SharePoint:ScriptLink name="sp.js" runat="server" OnDemand="true" 
      LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
  <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" FrameType="TitleBarOnly" 
      ID="full" Title="loc:full" />
</asp:Content>
```

And I just want to add, say, the SearchArea Web Part into the Zone I always get this on testing:
"Cannot create XmlSerializers for this Web Part"

This seems so simple and yet I always get this error. This essentially happens with ANY OOTB Web Part. What am I doing wrong? Again, I just have an App for SharePoint that will deploy a heavily customized Search experience, but MUST use the OOTB SharePoint controls for Search in certain areas.

Thoughts?

Comment: I having the same problem, but with the "Content Editor" OOTB web part, created, customized, and added within our feature activation event handler.  The XmlSerialization error occurs when the part is added to the page's web part collection, so I'm assuming the XML string was correctly handled when initially creating the web part.